# How do I find the latest version of an artifact from a maven repository

Tags: shell, maven-2, ant, artifactory

As part of an automated deployment I need a script to download the latest version of an artifact from our internal repository.

Ideally this script will be with ant or a unix shell script.

So for example:

I have myArtifact.war and it has versions 1.0 , 1.1 and 2.0 - I need the script given the correct group id and artifact id to retrieve version 2.0 from our maven repository (currently using artifactory).

Is there any easy way to do this?

Comment: In case you just need to check if the current artifact version is already released, here is a [nice plugin](https://github.com/chonton/exists-maven-plugin) that does that.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can parse the maven-metadata.xml to see what versions are available, and which version is the "release" version. See this answer about [plugin versions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1158131/how-does-maven2-know-where-to-find-plugins/1158210#1158210) for more details.

If you are using Nexus, you can use the [REST API](https://docs.sonatype.com/display/Nx/Nexus+Rest+API) to query the repository. You can also use the [REST client API](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.sonatype.nexus/nexus-rest-client-java) to simplify your processing.

To update the release version, activate the **release-profile** in the [Maven super POM](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-pom.html) when you do **mvn deploy**. You can do this by adding **-Prelease-profile** or **-DperformRelease=true** to the command line.

The profile is activate by default in the maven-release-plugin's perform goal. It is controlled by the *useReleaseProfile* property. See the [release-perform](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-release-plugin/perform-mojo.html) goal's documentation for more details.

Answer (score 21):

You can use the Maven Dependency Plugin goal `get` together with `LATEST` as version for your artifact:

```
mvn org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:get
    -DremoteRepositories=<URL_to_your_maven_repo>
    -Dartifact=<group_id>:<artifact_id>:LATEST
    -Dpackaging=jar
    -Ddest=<target_dir>/<artifact_name>.jar
```

Comment: Or `RELEASE`, which will exclude snapshots.

Comment: `RELEASE` and `LATEST` are no more supported in maven 3. See section 'Plugin Metaversion Resolution' of [maven compatibility notes](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/Maven+3.x+Compatibility+Notes#Maven3.xCompatibilityNotes-PluginMetaversionResolution).

Comment: `RELEASE` and `LATEST` are not supported by 'Plugin Metaversion Resolution', but they are still supported for normal dependency resolution, which is used in the answer above.